# std::shared_ptr which is null but not empty

Tags: c++, shared-ptr

Compare with: [std::shared_ptr which is empty but not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480691/stdshared-ptr-which-is-empty-but-not-null)

The `std::shared_ptr<T>` aliasing constructor lets us play interesting games. The above SO post discusses when the first argument is `std::shared_ptr<void>{nullptr}`. I'm interested in the reverse. Is this guaranteed to keep the pointed-to object alive even though the `shared_ptr` "is" `nullptr` (and would be completely unreachable if it weren't that we keep a reference to it)?:

```
std::shared_ptr<S> ps = std::make_shared<S>();
auto& s = *ps; // Keep a reference to the S.
auto p = std::shared_ptr<S>(ps, nullptr); // Aliasing c'tor with null pointer.
ps = nullptr;
assert(ps == nullptr);
assert(p == nullptr);
foo(s); //< Is the S still alive here?
```

https://godbolt.org/z/M19s54

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the "null but not empty" `shared_ptr` will keep the object alive because it shares ownership with the `shared_ptr` it was constructed from. All `shared_ptr`s that share ownership with each other contribute to an atomic reference count stored in the control block, and only when this reference count hits zero is the owned object destroyed.

For standardese, see [util.smartptr.shared.const]/14:

> `template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r, element_type* p) noexcept;`
> Constructs a `shared_ptr` instance that stores `p` and shares ownership with `r`

There are no constraints specified on the value of `p`; it may therefore be any valid pointer value, including null or even a past-the-end pointer (though I'm not sure why you'd want to do this).

Then see [util.smartptr.shared.dest]/(1.1):

> If `*this` is empty or shares ownership with another `shared_ptr` instance (`use_count() > 1`), there are no side effects.

In other words, when `ps` is destroyed, it still shares ownership with `p`, so the object is not destroyed yet.

The resulting object is not really unreachable in the usual sense, since it is still possible to destroy it. You just can't do anything else with it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `S` object is still alive when `foo()` is called, thus your `s` reference is still valid.

The *aliasing constructor* of `p` will increment the refcount of the `S` object that `ps` is currently holding, keeping that object alive, while `p` holds the `nullptr` that you gave its constructor.  When you are done using `p`, it will decrement the refcount.

You can verify this by querying the refcount:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<S> ps = std::make_shared<S>();
auto& s = *ps; // Keep a reference to the S.
auto p = std::shared_ptr<S>(ps, nullptr); // Aliasing c'tor with null pointer.
ps = nullptr;
assert(ps == nullptr);
assert(p == nullptr);
cout << ps.use_count() << endl; // prints 0
cout << p.use_count() << endl; // prints 1
foo(s); //< S is still alive here
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/h0In6Bvzj)

If you remove the `ps = nullptr;` statement, you will see both `ps` and `p` report the refcount is 2 instead:

```cpp
std::shared_ptr<S> ps = std::make_shared<S>();
auto& s = *ps; // Keep a reference to the S.
auto p = std::shared_ptr<S>(ps, nullptr); // Aliasing c'tor with null pointer.
//ps = nullptr;
assert(ps != nullptr);
assert(p == nullptr);
cout << ps.use_count() << endl; // prints 2
cout << p.use_count() << endl; // prints 2
foo(s); //< S is still alive here
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/gnixiPvqA)