# Why is empty weak_ptr required to store null pointer, while empty shared_ptr is allowed to store non-null pointer?

Tags: c++, c++17, weak-ptr

## Naive thinking

I expected the following assertion (1) to hold true for every valid value of `original` argument:

```
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>
    
void foo(std::shared_ptr<int> original)
{
    std::weak_ptr<int>    weak{original};
    std::shared_ptr<int>  restored{weak.lock()};  // lock() explicitly to avoid exception

    assert( restored == original );         // (1)
}
```

In other words, I thought that `weak_ptr` is supposed to be able to store the value of a `shared_ptr` in non-owning manner and then restore that original value later, when locked. Assuming the pointed object is still alive, of course.

## Reality

Obviously I was wrong, as the following test turned out to fail the assertion:

```
void test()
{
    int                       x = 42;
    std::shared_ptr<int>      empty_but_nonnull{std::shared_ptr<char>{}, &x};
    foo(empty_but_nonnull);
}
```

## Wording and test explained

`shared_ptr` can own one object, but store a pointer to some other object.
`shared_ptr` is called *empty* if it owns no object.
`shared_ptr` is called *null* if it points to no object.

A `shared_ptr` can be empty, but non-null. Such behavior is explicitly mentioned and allowed by the standard:

> [util.smartptr.shared.const]:
> 17. [Note 2: This constructor allows creation of an empty shared_­ptr instance with a non-null stored pointer.
> — end note]

Empty but non-null `shared_ptr` can be dereferenced, it is implicitly converted to `true` in conditional expressions, etc. No mention of the program being ill-formed whatsoever. So it seems to be perfectly legit and usable. It just says: "I'm pointing to an object that doesn't require any lifetime management, possibly to a global object with static storage duration, so what?".

However, an empty `weak_ptr` cannot be non-null. It is explicitly required by the standard to be null (emphasis mine):

> [util.smartptr.weak.const]:
> 4. `template<class Y> weak_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r) noexcept;`
> Effects: If r is empty, constructs an empty weak_­ptr object that **stores a null pointer value**

Which means that constructing a `weak_ptr` from an empty `shared_ptr` **loses the pointer** stored in original `shared_ptr`, forcing every empty `weak_ptr` to be null. After that, any attempt to reconstruct the original `shared_ptr` would obviously fail.

## The Question

What's the rationale behind the emphasized part of the quoted clause on `weak_ptr`? Why shouldn't `weak_ptr` store the same pointer as the original `shared_ptr`?

It's just that my original naive thinking doesn't seem that illogical to me...

---

Edit: Example edited to eliminate any possible exception and undefined behavior.

Comment: Because you're abusing the aliasing `std::shared_ptr`. You're not supposed to shove whatever the heck you like in there. It is implied that the stored pointer points to something that has lifetime that is closely related to the managed object. All semantics follow from that assumption. You shouldn't be surprised when your hammer doesn't work well as an egg breaker.

Comment: @PasserBy: 'You're not supposed to shove whatever the heck you like in there.' -- doesn't quoted clause [util.smartptr.shared.const.17] Note 2 disagree?

Comment: The standard giving you defined behaviour is not an endorsement of good code.

Comment: @PasserBy, ok. Maybe I should've started with a question "why empty but non-null shared_ptrs are allowed?"

Comment: That is unlikely to be answerable unless there's a specific proposal on it. I'd guess because not defining it introduces a whole lot of nuisance with no gain.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61480818/4885321

Comment: *"why empty but non-null shared_ptrs are allowed"* It's tempting to have an optionally owning pointer. It's essentially same as having a no-op deleter, but fancier and with less heap allocation.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, 'It's essentially same as having a no-op deleter, but fancier and with less heap allocation.' -- that was my impression too! So I was surprised to see that case called "an abuse"...

Answer (score 2):

`shared_ptr<T>` hold a pointer to a `T` and owns some object of type `U` which may or may not be the same as `T`. This feature exist to allow the `shared_ptr<T>` to point to some object that is a component of the `U` object that it owns. For example, you can create a `shared_ptr<derived_class>` and convert it to a `shared_ptr<base_class>` while still owning a `derived_class`. Or you can have a `shared_ptr<some_struct>` and create a `shared_ptr<some_structs_member>` which still owns a `some_struct`. Being able to do these things is the feature's purpose.

You will note that in the above cases, the object being pointed to is *owned by* the object being owned. That is, if the owned `U` object is destroyed, the `T` pointer held by the `shared_ptr` is no longer valid.

`weak_ptr<T>` is not a tool that is meant to be used to reconstitute a `shared_ptr<T>`. It is a tool that has one purpose: if a `shared_ptr` still exists which owns the memory weakly owned by the `weak_ptr<T>`, then you may extract a `shared_ptr<T>` from it.

`weak_ptr<T>::lock` does not care about the `T` pointer (it does preserve it, but it doesn't *care* about it); it only cares about *ownership*. Successfully `lock`ing a `weak_ptr` means that the object being managed is still alive. And the only definition of "successfully locking" is whether the `shared_ptr<T>` is `nullptr`. With the exception of `use_count` there is no observable difference between a non-null `shared_ptr<T>` that owns a `U` and a non-null `shared_ptr<T>` that doesn't own a `U`.

Remember: the expectation is that the `T` being stored is an object that is *owned by* `U`. Therefore, if a `weak_ptr<T>` is going to claim weak ownership over a `shared_ptr<T>`, and it finds that the `shared_ptr<T>` does not own anything... it assumes that the `T` is also destroyed. Because *that's what the feature is for*.

Now, could the constructor of `shared_ptr<T>` from a `shared_ptr<U>` also check to see if the `shared_ptr<U>` it is given actually owns something and throw an exception in that case? It could, but C++ is not a safe language. Furthermore, the only exceptions `shared_ptr<T>` constructors emit (other than implementation-defined ones) are from failure to allocate memory or failure to lock a `weak_ptr<T>`.

So at the end of the day, the standard assumes you know what you're doing when creating the `shared_ptr`.

Comment: I don't get this. If `T` is a base of `U`, then `U` doesn't own a `T`, but the `T` is part of the corresponding `U`.

Comment: @OlafDietsche: Ownership as a concept is about the destruction relationship between two objects. If destroying an instance of a `U` will necessarily destroy a particular `T` object, then that `U` object owns that `T` object. This is true of the relationship between derived classes and their base classes. Being "part of" something is an ownership relationship.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! You know, I'm not quite ready to agree that smart pointers are all about *owning* things. They are pointers in the first place, and pointers are about *pointing* to things... I've opened another question: [Why does the standard allow empty but non-null shared_ptr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75476575/why-does-the-standard-allow-empty-but-non-null-shared-ptr), let's see what answers it'll get.