# Why does the standard allow empty but non-null shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c++17, shared-ptr, language-design

1. This question is different from [std::shared_ptr which is empty but not null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61480691/stdshared-ptr-which-is-empty-but-not-null).
   That question is about solving a particular problem, while I'm asking about *the rationale and design reasons* behind a certain standard feature.
2. This question is a predecessor to another question: [Why is empty weak_ptr required to store null pointer, while empty shared_ptr is allowed to store non-null pointer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75469966/why-is-empty-weak-ptr-required-to-store-null-pointer-while-empty-shared-ptr-is) They share the same context, to some extent. However, I believe this question is self-contained and answerable in itself.

The C++ standard offers an aliasing constructor for `shared_ptr`:

```
template <typename T>
class shared_ptr
{
    template <typename U>
    shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<U>& r, element_type* ptr);
};
```

Such constructor means that a `shared_ptr` object can be created in a way that it owns one object, same as owned by `r`, while at the same time storing a pointer to another object -- `ptr`.

Also, the standard explicitly allows using this constructor to create a `shared_ptr` which doesn't own anything (thus meeting the definition of 'empty'), but still points to some object (thus qualified as 'non-null'):

> [util.smartptr.shared.const]:
> 17. [Note 2: This constructor allows creation of an empty shared_­ptr instance with a non-null stored pointer. — end note]

Construction of an empty but non-null `shared_ptr` could have been easily forbidden, for example by demanding that attempted construction of an empty `shared_ptr` instance with a non-null stored pointer should throw an exception.

But the standard chose to allow it. I wonder why and what for.

**What is the intended and canonical use scenario for an empty but non-null `shared_ptr`?**

Comment: *It is the responsibility of the programmer to make sure that this ptr remains valid as long as this shared_ptr exists*

Comment: It probably happened by coincidence when they made the aliasing constructor. So why not allow it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aliasing constructor was added to `std::shared_ptr` during standardization, in [N2351 "Improving shared_ptr for C++0x, Revision 2"](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2351.htm#aliasing):

> This feature extends the interface of `shared_ptr` in a backward-compatible way that increases its expressive power and is therefore strongly recommended to be added to the C++0x standard. It introduces no source- and binary compatibility issues.

At this time it was already noted that:

> [*Note:* This constructor allows creation of an *empty* `shared_ptr` instance with a non-NULL stored pointer. *--end note.*]

The aliasing constructor was at the same time added to `boost::shared_ptr`, which acted as a testbed: https://github.com/boostorg/smart_ptr/commit/54e12d03fdfec63b4d8ff41991c4e64af6b1b4b4 https://github.com/boostorg/smart_ptr/commit/ce72827dc73ac652ed07002b75f32e0171119c09

As for why this is permitted: there is a clear alternative, which is for the user to construct a `shared_ptr` from an existing pointer and a no-op deleter:

```
auto sp = shared_ptr(p, [](auto){})
```

However, this is less efficient than aliasing the empty state (since a separate control block must be allocated) and less expressive, since it is not possible to determine that the deleter is a no-op. So there is little reason to forbid the former.